# PostgreSQL: when we should set constraint_exclusion off?

Tags: postgresql, partitioning

From the official [document](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/ddl-partitioning.html), it seems "off" will spend a lot of time to check the partitioned and non-partitioned table to execute the plan. In such case, why we have off mode?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are misreading the documentation.

If you use partitioning, you should *not* disable `constraint_exclusion`, otherwise you won't have any advantages from partitioning during query execution, because all partitions will always be scanned.

On the other hand, if you don't use partitioning, and you have no check constraints on tables whose condition appears in queries regularly, it will save some planning time to disable `constraint_exclusion`.

If in doubt, stick with the default value (usually a good idea).

Answer (score -1):

Thats 9.1 documentation. In than version partitioning was incomplete. You must to write a trigger to separate the data in several partitions. If you are'nt sure of that trigger you must *set constraint_exclusion off*